# What is the best way to save the comments collected from Facebook using Python?

Tags: python, facebook, csv, facebook-graph-api

I'm collecting all the comments from some Facebook pages using Python and Facebook-SDK.

Since I want to do Sentiment Analysis on these comments, what's the best way to save these texts, such that it's not needed any changing in the texts?

I'm now saving the comments as a table and then as a CSV file.

```
table.to_csv('file-name.csv')
```

But if I want to read this saved file, I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position ...
```

By the way, I'm working with the German Texts.

Comment: Couple of questions. 1) how much data are you looking to store? 2) are you considering implementing some sort of DB to store them? 3) Is there any reason you shouldn't just use a csv file, despite the error which seems like a simple fix?

Comment: Thanks @NelsCarlson for the quick reply. 1) Currently, I can't say it exactly, because imagine I want to collect all the post messages from maybe 50 pages, and then filter the posts that I need according to the post message, and finally all the messages for each selected post. 2) No, For instance, for comments I defined a function and an empty list >> emptyList.append(..). 3) No, to me it's just important that I don't lose anything and the simplicity to retrieve the text for doing Sentiment Analysis.

Comment: Okay, since the data you're storing seems pretty relational (you find a post and then all the messages related to the post) I would recommend a JSON object. It'll just be saved to your computer like the CSV would, but the structure will probably make things easier. Something like {'post_id':001,'message':'hello'} might make preforming operations much simpler.

Comment: If you really wanted to you could even do something like this: {'post_id':001, 'messages':('message1','message2','message3')} and append the messages to the original post. A JSON will give you far more options for storing and thinking about your data than a CSV would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

Set default encoder at the top of your code

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")
```

or

```
pd.read_csv('file-name.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
```

Comment: Thanks @Toussaint, I tried this that way: pd.read_csv('file-name.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1") and now everything is working well! :)

Comment: @Vahid - if it works, can you mark the answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have knowledge about the encoding of the data then, you can simply use pandas to read your csv as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='encoding')
```

Comment: Thanks @Sijan, I know a bit about encoding, but so far I had always problem with this issue, could you please tell me how I can solve my problem :) so, I mean introduce me a source or a blog which has explained it more precisely! By the way, I'm working with the German Texts.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it really depends on many different factors such as:

- Size of the data
- What kind of analysis, specifically, are you anticipating that you'll be doing
- What format are you most comfortable working with the data

For most of my data munging in python I like to do it in pandas if possible, but sometimes that's not a feasible option given the size of the data. In that case you'd have to think about using something like pyspark. But here is a link to the pandas docs for reference, they have a lot of functionality for reading in all kinds of data: [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)